# Why is my layer shadow clipped to my NSView's rect?

Tags: cocoa, calayer, nsview

I'm creating a window containing an NSButton (both window content view & button have wantsLayer = YES), and setting the NSButton's shadowColor, shadowRadius, shadowOpacity and shadowOffset. But my shadow gets clipped to the rect of the NSView. How do I fix this?

```
NSRect          wdBox = NSMakeRect(0,0,100,100);
NSWindow    *   theWindow = [[[NSWindow alloc] initWithContentRect: wdBox styleMask: NSTitledWindowMask | NSClosableWindowMask | NSMiniaturizableWindowMask | NSResizableWindowMask backing: NSBackingStoreBuffered defer: NO] autorelease];
NSView* cv = [[[NSView alloc] initWithFrame: wdBox] autorelease];
cv.wantsLayer = YES;
[cv setLayerUsesCoreImageFilters: YES];
theWindow.contentView = cv;
[theWindow setCollectionBehavior: NSWindowCollectionBehaviorFullScreenPrimary];
[theWindow setTitle: @"foo"];

NSButton* mView = [[NSButton alloc] initWithFrame: NSMakeRect(10, 10, 100, 80)];
[mView setLayerUsesCoreImageFilters: YES];
[mView setWantsLayer: YES];
mView.layer.masksToBounds = NO;
[mView.layer setShadowColor: [NSColor.redColor CGColor]];
[mView.layer setShadowOffset: CGSizeMake(4, 4)];
[mView.layer setShadowRadius: 8];
[mView.layer setShadowOpacity: 1.0];
[mView setBezelStyle: NSRoundRectBezelStyle];
[mView setTitle: @"bar"];
[theWindow.contentView addSubview: mView];
```

Here's a picture:

[image: Clipped shadows on NSButtons]

I had similar code before and it used to work until 10.9, but the shadow suddenly got clipped to the view, so I rewrote it to this simple case, but it's still clipped.

Comment: did you include <QuartsCore/QuartsCore.h>?

Comment: I'm including Quartz, yes. Otherwise it wouldn't even compile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a bug in Mavericks. If you create an NSButton in XIB and give it a layer and set its shadow it works fine, but if you create one programmatically it clips its shadow.

I suspect the AppKit team did some crazy hacks when they made buttons do fast layer compositing in Mavericks (they won't redraw their backgrounds unless necessary now, for instance), because they tried to make it all happen magically, which is always always a bad idea.

Note that if you make an NSTextField the shadow code works as you'd expect. It's just NSButtons (so far) that I've found have this issue.

Please file a radar.

Comment: NSTextField draws it initially, then it disappears again, but yeah, seems to work fine for NSBox, for instance. Will test if using a XIB is maybe a workaround.

Comment: Thanks, Wil, that seems to do the trick: I created an NSViewController containing a button whose shadow I set in the XIB. Then I grab that button and add it to my window, change its attributes (I can change the button type etc., no ill effects), and magically it's no longer clipped.

Comment: Same applies to NSTextField. No disappearing shadow. I've just created a singleton NSViewController now with all the base views that have this problem, then copy a view (using NSKeyedArchiver etc.) whenever I need to instantiate one. rdar://15770532 (NSButton) and rdar://15770826 (NSTextField) in case anyone wants to file duplicates to hopefully get it fixed faster.